# Spin state coefficients in Stern-Gerlach experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, superposition, wavefunction-collapse

I'm trying to learn quantum mechanics basics by myself. I've been working on the Stern-Gerlach experiment. Now, positioning two apparatus both along the same direction (first z, then x and y) it is possible to retrieve some information about the $\left\vert \pm z \right\rangle$, $\left\vert \pm x \right\rangle$ and $\left\vert \pm y \right\rangle$:

$$ \vert \left\langle \pm x \vert \pm x \right\rangle \vert^2 = 1 $$
$$ \vert \left\langle \mp x \vert \pm x \right\rangle \vert^2 = 0 $$

$$ \vert \left\langle \pm y \vert \pm y \right\rangle \vert^2 = 1 $$
$$ \vert \left\langle \mp y \vert \pm y \right\rangle \vert^2 = 0 $$

$$ \vert \left\langle \pm z \vert \pm z \right\rangle \vert^2 = 1 $$
$$ \vert \left\langle \mp z \vert \pm z \right\rangle \vert^2 = 0 $$

now aligning the first apparatus along x and the second along z, it is possible to see that a $\left\vert \pm x \right\rangle$ can collapse with probability of $1/2$ to $\left\vert \pm z \right\rangle$, hence:

$$ \vert \left\langle \pm z \vert + x \right\rangle \vert^2 = 1/2 $$
$$ \vert \left\langle \mp z \vert - x \right\rangle \vert^2 = 1/2 $$

So, writing the x spin states as linear combination of the z spin states:

$$ \left\vert + x \right\rangle = \alpha \left\vert + z \right\rangle  + \beta \left\vert - z \right\rangle \Longrightarrow  \left\langle + x \right\vert = \alpha^* \left\langle + z \right\vert  + \beta^* \left\langle - z \right\vert$$

$$ \left\vert - x \right\rangle = \gamma \left\vert + z \right\rangle  + \delta \left\vert - z \right\rangle \Longrightarrow \left\langle - x \right\vert = \gamma^* \left\langle + z \right\vert  + \delta^* \left\langle - z \right\vert $$

Now, I understand that I can retrieve two conditions from the product $\left\langle + x \vert + x \right\rangle = 1 $

$$ \alpha^* \alpha + \beta^* \beta = 1 $$
$$ \vert \alpha \vert^2 = \alpha^* \alpha = 1/2 $$
$$ \vert \beta \vert^2 = \beta^* \beta = 1/2 $$

**Now, it seems that this two conditions aren't sufficient to determine all the coefficient unambiguosly: is the fact the almost always $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are chosen to be $1/\sqrt{2}$ arbitrary?**

Repeating the same reasoning for $\left\langle -x \vert +x \right\rangle = 0$ and $\left\langle +x \vert -x \right\rangle = 0$, I obtain the following conditions

$$ \gamma^* \gamma + \delta^* \delta = 1 $$
$$ \alpha^* \gamma + \beta^* \delta = 0 $$
$$ \alpha \gamma^* + \beta \delta^* = 0 $$
$$ \left\vert \gamma \right\vert ^2 = \gamma^* \gamma = 1/2 $$
$$ \left\vert \delta \right\vert ^2 = \delta^* \delta = 1/2 $$

**In this case too it seems that this five conditions, at the end, aren't sufficient to determine what $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are, therefore is the fact that they are choosen to be $1/\sqrt{2}$ and $-1/\sqrt{2}$ arbitrary?** If so, I assume that, when calculating coefficient for expressing $\left\vert \pm y \right\rangle$ in terms of $\left\vert \pm z \right\rangle$ and $\left\vert \pm y \right\rangle$ in terms of $\left\vert \pm x \right\rangle$ one can find thighter and thighter conditions until the last expression has completely determined coefficients

Thank you!